# Remove li tags using javascript array

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I'm searching a solution to remove `<li>` tags filtered using javascript array.

Array:

```
var mygroups=["1","8","3","4","5"]
```

Example (input):

```
<li><div>1 element.</div></li>
<li><div>2 element. This is my <span>post</span> into new group</div></li>
<li><div>3 element. Another one</li>
<li><div>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/1-first-group">First group</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><div><a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/10-ten-group">Ten group</a>5 element. This is my <span>new post</span></div></li>
<li>
   <div>6 element. <a href="/j1.5/index.php/jomsocial/63-zzz/profile">Actor</a></div>
   <div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/5-second-group">Group other</a></div>
</li>
<li>7 element.</li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/8-second-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/16-other-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/j1.5/index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid=1&Itemid=4">My other group </a></div></li>
```

How to get this output (Remove all instances which do not contain group in array in anchor):

```
<li><div>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/1-first-group">First group</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
   <div>6 element. <a href="/j1.5/index.php/jomsocial/63-zzz/profile">Actor</a></div>
   <div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/5-second-group">Group other</a></div>
</li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/8-second-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/j1.5/index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid=4&Itemid=4">My other group </a></div></li>
```

This code is not working right:

```
    $('li').filter(function() {
    var a = $(this).find('a');
    if (!a.length)
        return true;

    var text = a.attr('href').split('/')[3];
    text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('-'));
    if ($.inArray(text , mygroups) >= 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}).remove();
```

And this one does the job neither:

```
 $('li').filter(function() {
    if($(this).is('*:has(a[href|=/group/viewgroup/])') {
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
            trail = href.split('/')[3],
            number = + /(\d+)-/.exec(trail)[1];
        return $.inArray(myarray, +number) == -1;
    }
    return true;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do what you want. It's not the tidiest code in the world though:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    var a = $(this).find('a');
    if (!a.length)
        return true;

    var text = /(\d+)-/.exec(a.attr('href'))[1];  
    if ($.inArray(text , mygroups) >= 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}).remove();
```

It's getting all the li's, then filtering out any that have a matching value to the array and removing the ones that are left.

http://jsfiddle.net/8AmNR/5/

Comment: IMO, the code in the OP needs to be rethought; it would be far, far easier (and a little bit faster) to use `span`s with classes, or something, although the current implementation _does_ work.

Comment: Please check my details again. It can't find the second "A" tag.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a filter function.

In this scenario you select all the `li` and filter out the desired one.

```
$('li').filter(function(index){
    if(/*condition applied*/){
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: As you're not actually filtering, you should use `each` here to make the code more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$("li").each(function() {
          if($(this).find("a").size() == 0) {
              $(this).remove();
          };
    });
```

Comment: The anchor has to have 'group' in the href attribute.

Comment: This just removes all li's that don't contain an a take, the question stated that they should be filtered using the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    if($(this).is('*:has(a[href|=/group/viewgroup/])') {
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
            trail = href.split('/')[3],
            number = + /(\d+)-/.exec(trail)[1];
        return $.inArray(myarray, +number) == -1;
    }
    return true;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Please check my details again. It can't find the second "A" tag.