# Jquery filter function

Tags: jquery, html, filter, html-lists

May be you can help me.
I need to filter

tags using an array as follows:

```
<div id="els">
<ul>
<li><div>My example text<a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/13-first-group">Group one</a></div></li>
<li><div>My example text 2 <span>posted by Andrew</span></div></li>
<li><div>My example text 3</li>
<li><div>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/1-first-group">Group one</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li><div><a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/10-ten-group">Ten group</a>My example text. </div></li>
<li>
   <div>6 element. <a href="/j1.5/index.php/jomsocial/63-zzz/profile">Actor</a></div>
   <div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/5-second-group">Group other</a></div>
</li>
<li>7 element.</li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/8-second-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/16-other-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/j1.5/index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid=1&Itemid=4">My other group </a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My array:

var ids=["1","8","3","4","5"]

And I need to get this output (LI tags containing A tag with groupid in array):

```
<div id="els">
   <ul><li><div>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);">Actor</a>
         <a href="/groups/viewgroup/1-first-group">Group one</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
   <div>6 element. <a href="/j1.5/index.php/jomsocial/63-zzz/profile">Actor</a></div>
   <div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/5-second-group">Group other</a></div>
</li>
<li><div><a href="/groups/viewgroup/test/8-second-group">First group</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="/j1.5/index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid=4&Itemid=4">My other group </a></div></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: It looks like this should be handled in the server side, not with javascript/jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove li tags using javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064012/remove-li-tags-using-javascript-array)

Comment: This has been asked [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066164/remove-li-tags-3)... [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064012/remove-li-tags-using-javascript-array)... [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063370/jquery-remove-li-tags)... You should consider updating previous questions if you need more information, not ask the same question under a different username.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just use [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)